# What should one do if one sees a Tanach placed/shelved beside another religion's text?

Tags: jewish-books, tanach, books-generally

For example, a Tanach is being sold in a bookstore and it's placed right beside a New Testament/Christian Bible and a Quran. What should one do? Should one buy the copies to preserve its sacredness?

Comment: Where it's sitting on a shelf doesn't affect it. Unless you're particularly looking to buy a Tanach, just ignore it and move on.

Comment: @Shalom thanks for your response, may I ask on what basis (rabbinical opinion) you form this opinion from?

Comment: I hate to say this but ... proving a negative here ... there's nothing in the sources that indicates it *does* lose sanctity by where it's shelved. Really the only Talmudic source we have on storage of scripture was a problem when people stored the holy books next to food, and rodents were attracted to the latter and physically messed up the former. There's just no source about anything de-sanctifying a work of scripture. Say a fellow wrote a Torah scroll and subsequently became a heretic; we bury the scroll to not associate it with his heresy, but it's inherently still holy.

Comment: @Shalom I see. Thank you very much for taking the time to help me. I sincerely appreciate it and may Hashem always bless you.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Not everything has a rabbinical source. What @Shalom said is true. Sitting on a shelf next to an NT does not affect a Tanakh at all. Why would it?

Comment: You can see the situation described in thousands of public libraries.  No one is making any particular effort to change anything.